# Convert a text column to an array of json

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a column (Type TEXT) in my database where I store dynamic checklist items, stored in the following format: `[{"checked":"true","nome":"CNH Colorida"},{"checked":"false","nome":"Contrato social"},{"checked":"false","nome":"Última fatura de energia"}]`. I need to get which of them are checked, and which are not, using SQL. I used to have a PHP code that `json_decode` the string and then iterates it, but I want to be able to do this directly from the SQL. The PostgreSQL version is 9.4.

When I try to cast the returned row as json (`select valor::json`), nothing happens, and if I try to cast it to a json array (`select valor::json[]`), I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: malformed array literal: "[]"
Details: "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
```

By researches, I found that PostgreSQL arrays are defined with `{}`, and not `[]`. If I translate the `[]` to `{}`, I get this error:

```
SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: malformed array literal: "{{"checked":true,"nome":"Importado"},{"checked":false,"nome":"Finame"},{"checked":false,"nome":"MDA"}}"
Details: Unexpected array element.
```

What else can I try to get it working?

Comment: I think you're looking for `SELECT json_agg(<column>) ...`. You may need to use `unnest()` to remove the outer square brackets. Here is some documentation you can reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "nothing happens". What did you expect after casting a `text` value to `json` - that won't change the display.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the column type doesn't change to json, it stays as a text column. If I do the same typecast in a correct json format (not an array), the column type changes to json.

Comment: JSON is displayed the same way as text, so just from the display you can't really tell what type it is: https://i.imgur.com/sZcksqw.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have converted the text to json you need to unnest the array and extract the key values:

```
select d.v ->> 'nome' as name
from the_table t, json_array_elements(t.valor::json) as d(v)
where d.v ->> 'checked' = 'true';
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/TSRF14508

Comment: I wasn't using `::json` inside `json_array_elements`! After using it, I managed to get it working. Thank you so much!